# Loop including with ... as statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have the following Code:

```
    import urllib.request, json
    for i in range(10):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(baselink[i]) as url:
        data[i] = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

My baselink[i] are different URL strings. 
I am having difficulties to get my loop to run. Normally I am used to loops of the following type:

```
    for i in range(10):
        data[i] = something[i]
```

But I can't figure out how to get the loop to properly use the following "with ... as"-part:

```
    with urllib.request.urlopen(baselink[i]) as url:
```

The error message is : "IndentationError: expected an indented block" . I tried to put the part after ":" in brackets but that didn't solve the problem.
What I need as result is the outcomes of data[1], data[2], data[3], etc. ...

Comment: The error have nothing to do with the `with` statement. Read it again! Especially the first word: "IndentationError". You do know that blocks in Python uses indentation to denote scope?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have not come across any indentation issues yet, so this was new to me.